# Why does a function need to be bounded in order to have a Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose I have some piecewise smooth periodic function $f$.

Why does $f$ need to be bounded in order to have a Fourier series representation? Couldn't we consider the interval that it's unbounded as a finite point of discontinuities?

Comment: It is common to assume that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$, for example, which dictates that $f$ be bounded. You can allow singularities if you use improper Riemann integrals, but the description is bad if you want to allow many singularities. The Lebesgue integral is required if you want to allow general sorts of singularities, and that's not often in the vocabulary of the average student of Fourier Analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be bounded.  In order to define the Fourier coefficients (using the Lebesgue integral), you do want $f$ to be in $L^1$, i.e. $\int_I |f(x)|\; dx < \infty$ where $I$ is the interval you're using for your Fourier series.

Comment: So why do many people (including the authors of my textbook) throw in the added stipulation of boundedness? E.g., "We are tasked with finding a Fourier series of the bounded periodic function...".

Comment: @cbutler16 because those are the kinds of functions we can easily envision. It's harder to envision some of the wacky $L^1$ functions.

Comment: @CameronWilliams thanks mate!